# How to know if the Mac has retina?

Tags: image, macos, cocoa, retina-display

I have this code for changing the image of a button:

```
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"FloatingButton_hover"]]; }

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"FloatingButton_normal"]]; }
```

But i have @2x images of these 2 in my resources. How do i know if the Mac has retina, so i can `[self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"FloatingButton_normal@2x"]]`? Or is there any other way?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to do that. Just put your @2x versions in the same folder and Cocoa will take care of the rest. You can test if it's actually working by going into [HiDPI](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-enable-hidpi-display-mode-retina-like-in-os-x-lion-video/) mode.

I recommend watching [Introduction to High Resolution on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=213)

Comment: unfortunately, the HiDPI mode it's not working on my Mac. Btw, just to clarify, even when i'm coding and i write [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"FloatingButton_hover"]] cocoa chooses the FloatingButton_hover@2x automatically if the Mac has Retina, is that it?

Comment: Yes. But I still strongly recommend reading some of the documentation or watching the video above to learn about all the details.